# How to remove bulb mode on canonet ql 19?

Tags: canon, camera-settings, equipment-damage

I was testing my canon ql19 which seems to be in perfect working order. However I pressed the safety catch and set the camera to bulb mode and I can now not turn the ring back again. How are you meant to remove the B setting?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this "safety catch" button. There's nothing in the manual that leads me to believe that something like that exists (http://www.cameramanuals.org/canon_pdf/canon_canonet_ql19e.pdf) ***Manual linked from Mike Butkus, who does awesome work in assembling these old manuals. Consider throwing the man some money @ https://www.butkus.org/chinon/donation_policy.htm***

In general, though, attempt to "clear the slate" and start over. Wind the film advance lever making sure you get a full crank. Then use the shutter release. At this point, you should be able to adjust your shutter speed. With bulb mode, hold down the button and hear the shutter open. Keep it held down. Release a moment later and hear the shutter close. If you don't hear it close, then attempt to push the button again and it should close.

Please point out the button that you call "safety shift" as it's possible the use may have impacted the camera function. (If it's the self timer, and the self timer mechanism is broken...then you wouldn't be able to clear the slate)

Comment: My canon is probably a different generation and should work like this: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/554970/Canon-Canonet-Ql17.html?page=22#manual

Comment: I managed to remove the bulb mode, simply with the help of “magic touch”. However the shutter now no longer works at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user5227744 when you say that it doesn't work...does the advance lever cock the mechanism or not? If you go back to B, does it function again? If this was a car problem, you're essentially saying, "turning the key doesn't start the car." Okay...what else? Sounds, lights, details! List out everything you've tried and every detail.

Comment: Ok sorry. Yes I can pull the advance lever and there is a resistance as if it were cocking something. I can also press the shutter release button, and there is a very slight click sound but the shutter blades don’t move. On the other hand the aperture blades seem to function correctly. I can now enter and leave bulb mode without issue provided I press the safety catch. However the shutter blades are not moving under any circumstance. I also suspect the shutter speed ring is slightly harder to turn. However I may onlybe imagining this as it was fairly hard to turn jn the first place